# Problems with saving an int in NSUserDefaults iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsuserdefaults

I am using the below code to save an int and some other stuff into NSUserDefaults from my AppDelegate. The other array that I'm saving is full of objects that conform to NSCoding, so I don't think that that's an issue. If the current place is not zero, then that means that there is a session in progress, so all the data is loaded. When saving my data, it only saves if the current place is not zero which indicates that there is a session in progress. I know this calls when I exit the app on my physical device because the NSLog message appears in the debugger.

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {
// Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
// If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.

if (self.currentPlace != 0) {
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSMutableArray *arr = self.places; // set value
    NSData *data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:arr];
    [defaults setObject:data forKey:@"places"];
    [defaults setInteger:self.currentPlace forKey:@"current"];
    NSLog(@"Saving and Quitting b/c we have a place verified!");
    [defaults synchronize];
}
}

- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application {
// Called as part of the transition from the background to the inactive state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

NSInteger myInt = [defaults integerForKey:@"current"];

self.currentPlace = (int)myInt;

if (self.currentPlace != 0) {
    NSData *data = [defaults objectForKey:@"places"];
    NSArray *arr = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data];
    self.places = [arr mutableCopy];
    NSLog(@"Current Place: %i",self.currentPlace);
}

}
```

I am using my AppDelegate to store data that can be accessed from multiple screens in my app. In the first ViewController, the user is presented with a menu. If the appDelegate's currnentPlace value is *not* 0, then the option to continue with the loaded data from the AppDelegate is presented. However, this option is never presented. I check the currentPlace int's value using the following in my first view controller:

```
AppDelegate *delegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
[self setupViews];
self.spinner.alpha = 0;
NSLog(@"Current %i",delegate.currentPlace);

if (delegate.currentPlace == 0) {
    self.continueButton.enabled = false;
    self.continueButton.alpha = 0.5;
}
else if (delegate.currentPlace != 0) {
    self.continueButton.enabled = true;
    self.continueButton.alpha = 1;
}
```

If anyone could see what I'm doing wrong it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What value are you getting while logging this NSLog(@"Current %i",delegate.currentPlace);

Comment: I’m not sure because the app is disconnected from the Xcode debug session when I manually exit it by double clicking the home button and swiping up

Comment: But when I just click the home button once and come back in everything is fine and the currentplace loads correctly

Comment: Try putting your restoration code in `applicationDidBecomeActive:`.  I think `applicationWillEnterForeground:` is only for background/foreground switches.

Comment: That could be it. I will try it later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move your data restoration code block into a method, as below:

```
   - (void)restoreData {
       NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
       NSInteger myInt = [defaults integerForKey:@"current"];

       self.currentPlace = (int)myInt;

       if (self.currentPlace != 0) {
         NSData *data = [defaults objectForKey:@"places"];
         NSArray *arr = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data];
         self.places = [arr mutableCopy];
         NSLog(@"Current Place: %i",self.currentPlace);
       }
    }
```

Then call this method in `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` and `applicationWillEnterForeground:` methods in `AppDelegate`.

Comment: That's the one! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

You need to use

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
```

in you controller in which you are making the object of AppDelegate class.

If still you are not able to get current value then just store the value in user default as a string and when you acess it, convert it in appropriate data type which you want. Might be this could help you.